# Передача файлов WCF между клиентами по команде с сервера - как лучше организовать?

Tags: c#, wcf

требуется организовать очерёдность передачи файлов между клиентами в соответствии с определённой логикой - востребованности у клиента в файле с его свойствами и наличию у других клиентов файлов с такими свойствами

т.е. на сервере будет информация о всех файлах у клиентов из определённой папки, приобретённых свойств файла у каждого клиента и от клиентов будет поступать потребность в файлах с определёнными свойствами

Как правильно организовать такое? Можно ли передавать файлы не пропуская через сервер?

Comment: если мимо сервера, то клиенты должны видеть друг друга каким-либо образом, это может быть общая локальная сеть, физическая или виртуальная, или что-то типа торент-сети. Тут уж как вам нравится. Естественно клиент должен уметь принимать и/или отправлять файлы другим клиентам и сообщать информацию серверу. Т.о. клиентская программа должна быть и клиентом, и сервером по отношению к другим таким же программам для передачи файлов, а также клиентом сервера координации, для получения данных о других клиентах и необходимости получить от них них что либо. Как-то так. Есть и другие варианты

Comment: а вообще, вы практически полностью описали торент, так может и посмотреть как там сделано или воспользоваться готовым решением?

Comment: теперь понятнее стало, что чтобы клиенты могли что-то передать друг-другу на прямую, один из них должен стать сервером. по торрентам посмотрел после Вашего сообщения, слабо разбираюсь в теме торрентов, но на первый взгляд такое решение кажется более затратным - в плане - файл после каждого перемещения будет изменяться и скорее всего надо будет и сам торрент файл создавать каждый раз, хранить его на сервере, скачивать каждый раз, менее затратным кажется создание временного канала между клиентами - сервер-клиент - и передача массива байтов по BasicHttpBinding, в координации  с главным сервером